# Remove Post if Advanced Custom Field is checked to fix paging

Tags: php, wp-query, pagination, query-posts, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to setup a query that filters through posts and removes ones that have an ACF field "archived" checked. Post queries are pretty foreign to me.

```
query_posts("cat=10&posts_per_page=12&post_status=any&order=ASC"."&paged=".$paged);
```

How can I edit that string to check to see if the post has the `archived` checkbox checked? This is how I'm currently doing it, but because it's inside the loop, there are "phantom" posts that add to the pagination when they shouldn't.

`if(get_field('archived')) { /* my code */ }`

Thanks.

Comment: first, don't use `query_posts`. use `WP_Query`, or `pre_get_posts` if this is the main query. have a look at [`meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for fetching posts based on meta data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WP_Query instead, and you can use the meta_key / meta_value parameters:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'cat' => 10,
'paged' => $paged,
'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'archived',
    'meta_value' => 'true'
);          
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php while($posts->have_posts()): $posts->the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: So, this limits the posts correctly but the pagination isn't working at all now.

Comment: What I mean to say is the pagination doesn't even show up. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Never mind, got it working somehow. Not sure what I changed.